# How to set up cluster slave nodes (on Windows)

Tags: r, cluster-computing, snow, rparallel

I need to run thousands* of models on 15 machines (each of 4 cores), all Windows. I started to learn `parallel`, `snow` and `snowfall` packages and read a bunch of intro's, but they mainly focus on the setup of the master. **There is only a little information on how to set up the worker (slave) nodes on Windows. The information is often contradictory:** [some say that SOCK cluster is practically the easiest way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014778/684229), others claim that [SOCK cluster setup is complicated on Windows (sshd setup) and the best way to go is MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17551327/684229).

So, what is an easiest way to install slave nodes on Windows? MPI, PVM, SOCK or NWS? My, possibly naive ideas were (listed by priority):

1. To use all 4 cores on the slave nodes (required).
2. Ideally, I need only R with some packages and a slave R script or R function that would listen on some port and wait for tasks from master.
3. Ideally, nodes can be added/removed dynamically from the cluster.
4. Ideally, the slaves would connect to the master - so I wouldn't have to list all the slaves IP's in configuration of the master.

Only 1 is 100% required, 2-4 are "would be good". Is it too naive to request?

I am sorry but I have not been able to figure this out from the available docs and tutorials. I would be grateful if you point me out to the right source.

---

<sub>* Note that each of those thousands of models will take at least 7 minutes, so there won't be a big communication overhead.</sub>

Comment: R will handle workers. You just need to export all the functions and packages to them using ready made tools (in snowfall it's `sfExport` and `sfLibrary`).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, *"R will handle workers"* great to know, but the question was *how* - *how* shall I set them up? What cluster type you speak about?

Comment: Check out this for some example code and comments at the bottom about MPI vs. SOCK http://www.ics.uci.edu/~vqnguyen/talks/ParallelComputingSeminaR.pdf

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to include. I use snow on `SOCK`.

Comment: I don't think that the two answers you cited are contradictory. With one machine a SOCK cluster is pretty easy because ssh isn't used in that case. With multiple machines an MPI cluster is easier unless you are a Windows ssh expert.

Answer (score 2):

It's a shame how all these APIs (like parallel/snow/snowfall) are complex to work with, a lots of docs but not what you need... I have found an API which is very simple and goes straight to the ideas I sketched!! It is **redis and [`doRedis` R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRedis/index.html)** (as [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8417445/684229)). Finally a [very simple tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRedis/README) is present! Just modified a bit and got this:

**The workers need only R**, doRedis package and this script:

```
require(doRedis)    
redisWorker('jobs', '10.0.0.7') # IP of the server
```

The master needs [redis server](http://redis.io/) running (installed [the experimental windows binaries](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/blob/2.6/bin/release/) for Windows), and this R code:

```
require(doRedis)
registerDoRedis('jobs')
foreach(j=1:10,.combine=sum,.multicombine=TRUE) %dopar%
    ... # whatever you need to run
removeQueue('jobs')
```

**Adding/removing workers is fully dynamic, no need to specify IPs at master, automatic "load balanancing", simple** and no need for tons of docs! This solution fulfills all the requirements and even more - as stated in `?registerDoRedis`:

> The doRedis parallel back end tolerates faults among the worker processes and automatically resubmits failed tasks.

I don't know **how complex this would be using the parallel/snow/snowfall with SOCKS/MPI/PVM/NWS**, if it would be possible at all, but I guess very complex...

The only **disadvantages of using redis** I found:

- **It is a database server.** I wonder if this API exist somewhere without the need to install the database server which I don't need at all. I guess it must exist!
- There is a bug in the current doRedis package ([`"object '.doRedisGlobals' not found"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22340688/684229)) with no solution yet and [I am not able to install the old working doRedis 1.0.5 package into R 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22673474/684229).

Comment: doRedis indeed seems to be really an easy solution, however, I doubt that it does support multicore on the slaves. I tried to combine doRedis and doSNOW but failed. do you have any clues how to get the slaves running on multicore?